# React custom hook with callback parameter not picking up parameter change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, react-usecallback

I have a following generic custom hook. What I want to achieve is that hook itself exposes api with api functions, which I can use in a callback. I also want a hook to be dependent on a api function parameters changes.

```
export const useArticleApi = <TResult>(
    callback: (committedOrderApi: ArticlesApi) => Promise<TResult>
): {
    loading: boolean;
    data: TResult | undefined;
} => {
    const callbackRef = useRef<(articlesApi: ArticlesApi) => Promise<TResult>>();
    const [data, setData] = useState<TResult | undefined>();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        callbackRef.current = callback;
    }, [callback]);

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            setLoading(true);
            const response = await apiCallWithErrorHandling(
                async () => callbackRef.current && (await callbackRef.current(articlesApi))
            );
            if (response.isSuccess) {
                setData(response?.data);
                setLoading(false);
            }
        })();
    }, [callback]);

    return { loading, data };
};
```

Hook usage:

```
const getArticlesForAllCategoriesCallback = useCallback((api: ArticlesApi) => api.getArticlesForAllCategories(
        categories.map(c => ({ id: c.id, name: c.name, pageId: c.pageId }))
), [categories]);

const { data, loading } = useArticleApi<ArticleSearchBarViewData>(api => getArticlesForAllCategoriesCallback(api));
```

I missing something pretty obvious, but for some reason `useEffect` inside the hook doesn't detect the change of callback parameter and api method is run only once. Can you spot the issue?

Comment: With the code you show I would expect both of the effects to be triggered each render. The parameter 'callback' you provide will be a new arrow function on each render. What you probably want to do is spilt callback and paramter, two parameters for your hook.

Comment: @nil actually, I don't want to split, since the main idea is to have it generic and by wrapping ```getArticlesForAllCategories``` with ```useCallback``` I'm only expecting it to change once ```categories``` dependency changes